# Google Map Activity will not support in Android Studio 3.0.1 API 24

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin

[image: build.gradle(module:app)]

I desire to develop Location Tracker Application using Google Map on Android Studio 3.0.1. Therefore, I have been selected Google Map Activity for XML.

But It is not supported.The error like

[image: All imported classes are in error mode]

[image: All methods are in red and Gradle sync failed]

Comment: show me your gradle.build

Comment: Please, next time paste your code/error instead of using images. People will downvote you if you use so many images.

Comment: You need to do a lot more than just adding that one line of Gradle. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Answer (score 0):

You need to [include Google repository](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Add this to your `build.gradle` (top level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added classpath

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

in project level `build.gradle` file and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

google-services plugin in module level `build.gradle` file